# Derivative of $ r(t) = at\cos(3t)i + b (\sin(t))^3j + c (\cos(t))^3k$

Tags: calculus

Component wise derivatives I get:

$x =$ ?

$y = (\sin(t))^3 + 3b\cos (t)(\sin(t))^2$

$z = (\cos(t))^3 - 3c\sin(t)(\cos(t))^2$

Not sure on what $x$ is. Do I use:

$f(x) = at $

$g(x) = \cos(3t)$

then $f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$ to get the derivative of the i component?

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful. If you need to format more advanced things, there are many excellent references on LaTeX on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a mix of product and chain rule.

I denote $r(t)=x(t)i+y(t)j+z(t)k$. So $r'(t)=x'(t)i+y'(t)j+z'(t)k$.

Note that your $y'$ and $z'$ are not correct.

You have:

$$
x'(t)=a\cos(3t)-3at\sin(3t)
$$
$$
y'(t)=3b(\sin t)^2\cos t
$$
$$
z'(t)=-3c(\cos t)^2\sin t
$$

Let me know if you need me to expand.

Comment: Had a feeling those weren't right either. I got it thanks.